# Exporting several arrays from all documents in a mongodb database

Tags: arrays, list, mongodb, search

Mongodb's documentation does not seem to cover this. After several hours of mixing different commands I stand defeated.

I have hundreds of documents inside a collection in a mongodb database. In every document I have an array called "hashes", in most documents this array contains a list of hashes (MD5, SHA1 etc...). I want to export all these hashes to a text file, or list them all in a GUI/terminal.

I've included an image where what I want to export is highlighted in yellow.
[image]

Comment: You could write a small script/javascript and put these hashes into a different collection, then export that collection using http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command was derived from the documentation Lalit Agarwal provided. It does exactly what I wanted.

./mongoexport --port 27017 -db paste_db -collection pastes --fields hashes --csv > out.csv